# get data ( favourite item ) from localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

> **How to get favourite item from list item app .  i am using ionic 4 . my json data added localstorage but  not get added data properly.**

**favourite.service.ts**

```
getAllFavoriteItems(){
    return  this.storage.get("object");
  }

  isFavorite(favorite) {
    return this.getAllFavoriteItems().then(result => {
      return result && result.indexOf(favorite) !== -1;
    });
  }

  favoriteItem(favorite) {
    return this.getAllFavoriteItems().then(result => {
      if (result) {
        result.push(favorite);
        return this.storage.set("object", result, );
      } else {
        return this.storage.set("object", [favorite]);
      }
    });
  }

  unfavoriteItem(favorite) {
    return this.getAllFavoriteItems().then(result => {
      if (result) {
        var index = result.indexOf(favorite);
        result.splice(index, 1);
        return this.storage.set("object", result);
      }
    });
  }
```

**favourite.page.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.storage.get("object").then((ids) => {
      console.log( 'favouriteIds' ,ids)
      this.favouriteIds = ids;
    })


    // this.favouriteIds = this.favoriteService.getAllFavoriteItems();
    // console.log('favitems',this.favitems)
}
```

**favourite.page.html**

```
<ion-content no-padding color="secondary">
<ion-list> 
  <div class="main">
      <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of favouriteIds" [routerLink]="['/','details',item.id]" 
      class="item-native" (click)="showInterstitial()">
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <img [src]="item.thumnailUrl">
        </ion-thumbnail>

        <ion-label>{{item.title}}</ion-label>
        <ion-label>{{item.id}}</ion-label>

      </ion-item>

 </div>


</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

full list item in screenshot 
[image]

Favourite list item  in this , but not get properly favourite item

[image]

Comment: what is that first image? Where are the items coming from... where are you setting things to favorite list? What is that first console log executed from and when? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: **home.page.ts : (page 1)**      `ngOnInit(){
    this.recipiservice.getData().subscribe(results =>{
        this.items = results;
    });
  }`
**recipi.service.ts :(page 2 )**  `getData(){
    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(this.url);
    return data;
}`

Comment: doesn't really answer any of my questions. Please create a [mcve], best would be to create a stackblitz, then you also what code is necessary to reproduce the issue :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-app-ptpqm4

Comment: Sadly that stackblitz doesn't work...

Comment: what it is mean ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-app-ptpqm4?embed=1

Comment: link not work ??

Comment: link works, but the stackblitz doesn't. It throws just errors.

Comment: I didn't write all that code here ।

Comment: just//some code..write..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198127/discussion-between-user7379812-and-ajt-82).

Comment: now,what can i do ?

Comment: create a **minimal, working sample** of the stackblitz please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse it to JSON, once you retrieve from local storage,

```
 this.favouriteIds = JSON.parse(ids);
```

Comment: please more details .tnx for ans

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: post what is the output of console.log(ids);

Comment: ngOnInit() {
  
    this.storage.get("object").then((ids) => {
      this.favouriteIds = JSON.parse(ids);
      console.log( 'favouriteIds' ,ids)
    })
}

Comment: which does not seem to be like an array

Comment: now what can i do ?  please help me . tnx for advance